# How do you bootstrap a $resource in Angular

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js

Back in the backbone days, I used to bootstrap some model-data in a server-parsed-global-object like this:

```
<head>
<script>
  window.GlobalExpress = {
    modelData: { ... },
    collectionData: [ ... ]
  };    
</script>
</head>
```

and then when the app initialized, I initialized my models like this:

```
var SpecialModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... });
var aModel = new SpecialModel(GlobalExpress.modelData);

//persist model updates
aModel.save({ ... });


var SpecialCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ ... });
var aCollection = new SpecialCollection(GlobalExpress.collectionData);

//persist collection updates
aCollection.sync();
```

But these are different times. And with angular's $resource I have no idea how to initialize with bootstrapped data. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in AngularJS. Even better, wrap them in a service. Other possiblity is to use [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope).

Comment: Look, I get that you can glue data here and there. Reason i'm asking this are the convenience crud methods: model.$save(), model.$update() and such.. You don't get that if you just glue what you bootstrapped. Right?

Comment: You can't really use global objects like this with resource. Why no just expose api and consume it with resource. The only reason will be you have do to extra http request.

Comment: For a single resource it's one request. For 10 resources it's 10 requests :}

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Restangular:

```
var user = Restangular.all('users');
_.extend(user, Restangular.restangularizeCollection(null, objectData, 'users'));
```

[Source](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/190)